# How to share a data-uri image on Pinterest?

Tags: javascript, html, api, share, pinterest

I want to share a data-uri image on pinterest.

I've come up with the following markup:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/">
  <img class="pin-image" src="data:image/png;base64,…">
</a>
```

At the end of my body I am including this JS:

```
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  async defer
  src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"
></script>
```

Usually, the pinit.js should pick up the src of the img tag inside the link, but when I open up the link I don't see the image I want to share.

I've also tried to share without the pinit.js by adding GET parameters to the URL, but my data-uri is too long.

My researches haven't given me helpful advices on sharing generated images on pinterest, so hopefully on of you guys has an answer for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily update the anchor tag with the proper URL and avoid loading of that **pinit.js** script..

The basic GET method does the trick...

I quickly wrote a function that will do that for you.
You just need to pass the img selector to it and it will find all occurrences and apply the logic.

**DEMO:**
https://jsfiddle.net/zmgyc0bd/

```
function pinterestShareFormatter(imgSelector) {
    var imgs = document.querySelectorAll(imgSelector),
        baseUrl = '//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?';

    [].forEach.call(imgs, function(img) {
    var imgSrc = img.getAttribute('src'),
        articleUrl = img.getAttribute('article-url') ? img.getAttribute('article-url') : window.location.href, //  check if there is article url attribute and if not assign the current page url.
        parentAnchorEl = img.parentNode;

    // check if parent element is <a>
    if(parentAnchorEl.tagName === 'A') {
      // format the url params
      var params = {
        url: articleUrl,
        media: imgSrc
      },
      paramsString = Object.keys(params).map(function(key){return key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[key]);}).join('&');

      // update the anchor with formatted url
      parentAnchorEl.setAttribute('href', baseUrl + paramsString);
    }
  });
}

pinterestShareFormatter('.pin-image');
```

- make sure you are calling this function on a right place for you.

Comment: I'm getting a 502 HTTP Error on Pinterest. Probably the URL is too long?

Comment: Sorry for late reply... That is most probably the case, I forgot for a second about the URL length limit. If the image is large baseline64 will be huge. Which brings us back to the pinitjs... Or maybe we can do the POST request with the same params (simple as wrapping each image in form tag, maybe it sounds hacky but is worth to try). I will take a look.

Comment: Is there a parameter for sending a title and text?